# Enable or disable File->New popup menu based on perspective change

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I have created a extension point newWizard and there I have added wizards (Let's say wizard1, wizard2, wizard3).
I have created a perspective i.e perspectiv1.
and When I create a plugin project all the wizard labels are added in 
File->New pop up menu right click of the created project.
But the issue is if I am changing the perspective to java, then all the wizard labels are showing in my File->New pop up menu right click of the created project.

Can anyone please suggest how to handle the scenario above. I want to restrict those wizard labels to be visible only when I select my own created perspective i.e perspectiv1.

Thank You

Comment: The new wizard does not support this. You might be able to do something with the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point but it will be hard.

Comment: @greg-449, could you please suggest me how to handle this if I use org.eclipse.ui.activities. Because I have tried to use this but this is restricting my perspective1 also

Comment: You would probably have to use the `IActivityManager` to enable / disable entries dynamically. But doing this is really wrong. The New wizard is intended to always show everything all the time. If you have something that does not fit that it should not be a normal new wizard.

Comment: As someone working in the same project: What we try to achieve is that in our custom perspective, the wizards appear as suggestion in New context menu, but not in other perspectives (in other perspectives you have to go to Other to see the wizards). I think the relevant extension point is `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent` with the `commonWizard` element, but we don't know how to configure the `enablement` element to only enable this in our perspective.

Comment: @kutschkem You use the 'newWizardShortcut` in the org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions extension point for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the problem. The issue was I was adding all the created wizards in the navigator content to show those in navigator but it was making active in all the perspectives. I have solved it following below steps:

Step1: First I have removed the commonWizrad option from `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent` in extensions

Step2: Added `popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer`
In the locationURI set the value "popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions"

Step 3: Added "menuContribution" on right click of the project explorer extension and in the locationURI set the value "popup:common.new.menu?after=new"

Step 4: Added "command" on the right click of menuContribution  and set commandID ="popup:common.new.menu?after=new"

Step 5: Right click on the "command" added "parameter" and set the name and value as I have created for the wizard

Step 6: Right click on the "command" added "visibleWhen", set false
This value will be active based on the your perspective. So in the variable set the  active woorkbench perspective equals to the perspective you want.

Thank you